# prevent expand to textarea

Tags: html, css

I am using IE8 and I have textarea on the page. It's width set to 80% with maxlength of 132 chars.
If the user write text that not contains spaces, like the letter V 132 times without spaces, the textarea grows horizontaly (width grows).
How can I prevent this behaviour - I don't want allow the width to grow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add:

```
textarea
{
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use word-wrap: break-word; to wrap the long unbroken line.

```
textarea
{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bLKPq/2/

Comment: I don't want to hide the text - I just want to prevent the textarea from expanding.

Comment: You want to prevent it from expending, or to limit the input size?

Comment: @Naor overflow hidden hide the scrollbar even though you can see the expanded text.

Comment: @Michael Sazonov: prevent it from expending.

Comment: @punit: putting long text without spaces expand the textarea width and this is what I want to prevent.

Answer (score 1):

Set rows and cols property to it